# ScrollIntoView of other component not workng (type error)

Tags: html, angular

Im trying to have a navigation menu where you the menuitems let you scroll to the specific card on the page. This works fine when the user is on that exact page. But I also want it to work when the user is not on that page.
I have tried to first navigate to the correct page and then scrollIntoView of the specific card. But that is giving me a type error. If I click it a second time, it will scroll just fine.

This is the code I am using to scroll into the correct card:

```
//sroll to calendar
  async calendar() {
    this._router.navigate(["/Home"]);
    const elmntToView = document.getElementById("Calendar");
    elmntToView.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'}); 
    this.toggleHidden()
  }

  //scroll to export
  export() {
    this._router.navigate(["/Home"]);
    let elmntToView;
    elmntToView = document.getElementById("Export");  
    elmntToView.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
    this.toggleHidden()
  }
```

I first navigate to the correct page (Home) and then iI am calling the document.getElementById() method, but that is giving me an error:

[image: TypeError]

Is there any way to fix this? For me it seems like the docment.getElementById() is called before the navigation is finished, but I also tried to await the navigation, but that still causes the same problem...

Comment: the scrollIntoView will not be executed since you have performed redirection first and those code blocks after it will not be executed.

Comment: If this is the issue  `getElementById()` is called before navigation finished, you can use `ngAfterViewInit()` or in your  template   `header.component.html`
whee this property/ method calling you can use `*ngIf`. if you share `stackblitz` that will be helpful to fix .